# Reference: Computing Martin Capacity

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, brownian-motion, geometric-measure-theory, potential-theory

For Borel set $A$ the Martin Capacity is defined as:

$\mathrm{Cap}_{M}(A)=[\inf\{\int \int \frac{G(x,y)}{G(0,y)}d\mu(x)d\mu(y):\mu \mbox{ probability measure on }A \}]^{-1}$ and Green's function $G(x,y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{d/2}}e^{\frac{-|x-y|^{2}}{2t}}dt$.

I didn't find any references online. All I found was http://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/martin.pdf.  But they don't compute any Martin capacities there.

Ideally a step to step process.

Or at least a way to get estimates ,say, for compact sets.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you consulted Peter Morter's book "Brownian Motion"? Chapter 8.3.  It is explained there that Martin Capacity is zero if and only if the F-capacity is zero (where F is the potential kernel). I guess it only matters whether capacities are positive or zero, so this migh be helpful.